# MagicSuggest dependent multiple dropdowns not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, dropdown, magicsuggest

I am using MagicSuggest for custom dropdown, now I have two dropdowns category and sub category.. sub categories should be populated based on category selection. When I select category, and then subcategory, it will work for the first time, but if I change the category sub categories will not change and shows the same list.
here is my jquery..

```
var cat = $('#category').magicSuggest({
    maxSelection:1,
    data: site+'project/getCats/',
    valueField: 'id',
    displayField: 'title',
    mode: 'remote',
    renderer: function(data){
        return '<div>' +
                '<div class="title">' + data.title + '</div>' +
            '</div>';
    },
    resultAsString: true,
    selectionRenderer: function(data){
        return '<div class="name">' + data.title + '</div>';
    }
});
$(cat).bind('selectionchange', function(event, combo, selection){
    cat_id = cat.getValue();
    src = site+'project/getCats/'+cat_id;
    var subcat = $('#sub_category').magicSuggest({
        maxSelection:1,
        data: src,
        valueField: 'id',
        displayField: 'title',
        mode: 'remote',
        renderer: function(data){
            return '<div>' +
                    '<div class="title">' + data.title + '</div>' +
                '</div>';
        },
        resultAsString: true,
        selectionRenderer: function(data){
            return '<div class="name">' + data.title + '</div>';
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Since no one is replying I will take the risk..

Taken from Magicsuggest home page http://nicolasbize.com/magicsuggest/doc.html.

I think you need to use the setData() which sets the objects listed in the combo.

```
var ms = $('#ms-setData').magicSuggest({});
ms.setData(['Paris', 'New York', 'Gotham']);
$(ms).on('selectionchange', function(){
    alert(JSON.stringify(this.getSelection()));
    this.setData([
        {id:1, name:'Blue'},
        {id:2, name:'Red'}
    ]);
});
```

If you go to the link I posted above, you will find a working example. You first choose a city eg Paris and then the options are changed in colors so you can select blue.

You can tweak your code to use the setData on the "sub_category"..